# Google Maps: Display the current users location with a custom marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following example that displays the current users location on a Google map: http://dev.driz.co.uk/googlemap/

As you can see I have three pieces (I have borrowed Foursquare icons for the demo):

1.) The marker where the user is located

2.) The avatar of the user (note this may changed dependant if the user is logged in or not and has a custom avatar or just has the mystery man)

3.) The avatar frame that sits on top of BOTH the avatar and the marker.

**What I want to do is make it so that the avatar sits nicely inside the frame perhaps as a background image instead if that's possible? Not seen anything in the docs about this, but the frame needs to be above the avatar so it creates the rounded corners mask.**

**And also I want them to fall down all together as sometimes the frame appears below the marker dot and not always on top as it should be. So they need to act as one piece and drop at the same time.**

Can anyone with Google Map knowledge help me out with these two parts? Thanks

Comment: Just as a note, it's more useful if you could reproduce your existing code here as a resource to future users who browse the question, in the event your link no longer leads anywhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things worth noting about the entire animation as it stands:

- Marker z-index is inconsistent during animation since it is not set until the marker is in its final position, so the only thing you can really do to control that during the drop is to order your calls to each marker's **`setMap`** function as best as you can to coax them to stack in order while dropping. That means calling the back-most object's function first, proceeding to closer images in the stacking order. Once the animation is done, however, they will invariably be in the correct order.
- In order to control the order of the **`setMap`** calls, you're going to have to uniquely name the variables that store your **`Marker`** objects.
- Markers aren't added to the map and animated until they load, so it would probably be best to create image objects in code and pre-load your images, then set the marker animation as a callback from the **`onload`** event once they're all finished.

Even with all this in place, the images are still going to drop individually so it may not have exactly the effect you're looking for, but this is probably the way to get it as close as can be managed.

**Setting Z-Index**

First, the z-index of your markers can be easily set as one of the [**`MarkerOptions`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) you pass in to the **`Marker`** constructor:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    icon: image1,
    zIndex: 1
});
```

**Setting Icon Anchoring**

Next, to change the positioning of the image you provide to the marker, the **`MarkerOptions`** object can contain [**`MarkerImage`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) as its **`icon`** member, so use this object to indicate the anchor of your icon:

```
var image1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1597153/00000000000000000000000000000000.png",
    null,
    null,
    new google.maps.Point(16, 49));
```

The second and third parameters are optional and will be constructed for you if not specified, so we are really only interested in providing a value for the anchor parameter.

**Creating an Image OnLoad Callback**

If you're going to pre-load the images, which I highly recommend, do so by creating three image objects, binding an OnLoad handler to each object, and then setting the image's **`src`** property—**in that order**. Your code to create markers and add them to the map should only happen once all three images have loaded.

```
// Create image objects to force pre-loading
var domImg1 = new Image(),
    domImg2 = new Image(),
    domImg3 = new Image();

// Instantiate variables for iteration
var images = [domImg1, domImg2, domImg3],
    j = 0;

// Bind an OnLoad handler that checks to see if all three images have been pre-loaded
for (i in images) {
    images[i].onload = function() {
       if (++j == 3) {
           // Create markers and add to map here
       }
     }
}

// Set the src property to start the download and trigger the onload events
domImg1.src = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1597153/00000000000000000000000000000000.png";
domImg2.src = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1597153/pin-white.png";
domImg3.src = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1597153/marker.png";
```

I've provided a working demo of the techniques I've demonstrated here on [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/5uGLf/), so check it out and it will hopefully give you an idea of how it comes together.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just had a quick play and for me the items still appear one after the other so for a second they are all out of sync. Is it possible to make them drop already together? Also fixed the zindex issue :P but the above is still an issue.

Comment: Not really. That was part of the initial notes I offer you. There's no real way to control that. The only other suggestion I can make is combining the marker and picture frame into a single image to limit the incongruities.

Comment: What about disabling the animation or using a different animation?

Comment: I'd say dump the animation because you're probably going to run into it with anything other than a stationary effect, such as a fade-in for instance, which isn't an option.

Comment: In the docs I only see two options either drop or bounce... How would I disable the animation? Thanks

Comment: Remove the parameter from the options you pass to the constructor. An **`animation`** member is not required to create a marker.